# Copying a md5sum output to string in C program

Tags: c

I am trying to copy the md5Sum output to string using sprintf function. But when I print the output string, its always showing as zero. What is the mistake I am doing here?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
  char command[50];
  char buffer[50];
  int len;
  puts("Enter the password");
  fgets( buffer, 50, stdin);
  strcpy(command, "echo -n ");
  len = strlen(buffer);
  if (buffer[len - 1] == '\n')
  buffer[len - 1] = '\0';   
  strcat(command, buffer);      
  strcat (command, "| md5sum");
  system(command);
  bzero(buffer, 50);
  sprintf(buffer, "%x", system(command));
  puts(buffer);
  return(0);
  }
```

Output:

```
elcot@boss:~$ ./md5sum
Enter the password
Karthi
51ea12796f11f1f4b72fa9316c45ead3  -
51ea12796f11f1f4b72fa9316c45ead3  -
0
```

Comment: The return value of `system` is not what you think it is. "0" indicates "success".

Comment: what is way to copy the result of system(command)? and save it to a character array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try "popen" function:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
  char command[50];
  char buffer[50];
  int len;
  puts("Enter the password");
  fgets( buffer, 50, stdin);
  strcpy(command, "echo -n ");
  len = strlen(buffer);
  if (buffer[len - 1] == '\n')
  buffer[len - 1] = '\0';   
  strcat(command, buffer);      
  strcat (command, "| md5sum");
  //system(command);
  bzero(buffer, 50);

  FILE *lsofFile_p = popen(command, "r");

  char *line_p = fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), lsofFile_p);
  pclose(lsofFile_p);

  printf("%s",buffer);

  return(0);
  }
```